# Twitter Bootstrap grid logo and nav bar same row with nav aligned to bottom of row

Tags: html, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express, pug

[image] 
I am trying to have a circular logo placed to the left of a bootstrap nav menu and have the menu align with the bottom of the row but it always wants to align with the top.  I wrote this in jade but hopefully people with other languages can at least understand how it works (indents signify nestings instead of having closing tags).  Is there a way i can easily do this with css or using the grid system in bootstrap?

```
doctype 5
html
    head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/bootstrap.min.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')

    body
        .container
            .row

                .span3
                    img(id='add-razaoSocial', src='KSUB_PLATTER_Full.png', width=100)
                .row

                        .span9
                            .navbar(class="pull-left")
                                    .navbar-inner
                                        a(class='brand')
                                        ul(class="nav nav-tabs")
                                            li 
                                                a(href='#') About
                                            li 
                                                a(href='#') Schedule
                                            li 
                                                a(href='#') Events
                                            li 
                                                a(href='#') Gallery
            block content
            script(src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js')
            script(src='/js/bootstrap.min.js')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is coming from creating the tabs you want inside of a navbar (and inside navbar-inner, which wraps your tabs).  The tabs you're trying to achieve don't need to be wrapped inside a navbar (which is pretty well designed to be fixed/static to top or bottom). See their documentation for nav-tabs http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navs

A standalone `<ul class="nav nav-tabs">` should be much easier to wrap and set margins/padding.  Might also set the CSS position property of the row beneath your image to be absolute. and contents relative.